# Sending and getting data from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, express

I have created a rest api in nodejs

i have the get request function like this:

```
server.js

const search = 'example' //user input search variable changes based on input from html file
app.get('/api/getData', (req, res) => {
    var url = 'externalapiurl' + search // so you can see that my requests depends on the users input search variable
    request(url, function (err, response, body) {
           var data = 'json loaded data'
           res.send(data)
    });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
```

i also have a html file and another script.js that has a search button where the user can type in a string and that string i want it to be the 'const search' in the server.js and then after that to return it back to the html file just to test it.

```
   index.html script.js                             server.js               script.js index.html
     ----search-----    ---->       puts string into const search    ----> send back to html and display as text
```

this might help with the html search button

```
server.js



const searchbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("search-btn")[0];
searchbtn.addEventListener("click", getAns);

function getAns() {
var search = document.getElementById("input").value;
//what do i do now?
}
```

how do i call the get function to my api from my script.js file, taking subreddit variable with it into server.js and then sending it back to html file.

Comment: first : why should you start the question with "So" ? is it a continuation of another conversation ? then : what is your main question ?

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti ok.... i got rid of the 2 letters 'So'

Comment: I think there's the second part of my request left that you did not read

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti what do you mean? 'what is your main questions'? the question is there....

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti  how do i call the get function to my api from my script.js file

Comment: edit this in your question